# v6 redux-form, reduxForm() mapDispatchToProps return error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to get the form I created with v6 redux-form to render in my App component  to display in the browser. However, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: `mapDispatchToProps` must return an object. Instead received function () {
              return computedActions;
            }.
```

My LoginForm component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form'

class LoginForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <Field
            name="email"
            component="input"
            type="text"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <Field
            name="password"
            component="input"
            type="password"
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default reduxForm({ form: 'login' })(LoginForm)
```

App.js imports LoginForm component:

```
import React from 'react'

import LoginForm from '../containers/LoginForm'

export default () =>
  <div>
    <LoginForm />
  </div>
```

My top-level index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import reducers from './reducers'
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'
import App from './components/App'

const store = configureStore()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'))
```

Relevant dependencies:

```
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "4.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-form": "^6.6.3"
```

Any Insight to a solution is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem by updating react-redux to the latest version 5.x